# This question is based on basic counting.

Tags: combinatorics

How many 10- digit numbers containing digits 1,2&3 can be formed such that the first & the last digits are same and no two consecutive digits are same?

Comment: This problem is a combinatorial one. Nothing to do with number theory.

Comment: This is not number theory per se. It is rather basic counting.

Comment: ... and it was asked by someone else literally yesterday.